# jquery - scrolling the background

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I wanted to achieve is a logo with png transparency and the background which automatically scrolls down so it gives an effect like it's made in flash. I used jquery.backgroundPosition.js plugin, which enables background scrolling.

The code:

HTML

```
<div id="logo">
    <h1><img src="img/logo.png" alt="The logo" width="420px" height="420px" /></h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#logo {
margin: 150px 400px;
display: block;
width: 420px;
height: 420px;
overflow: hidden;
background: transparent url('../img/bg.jpg') repeat-y 0 -1500px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#logo').animate(
        {backgroundPosition: '0 -99999999px'},
        {duration: 5550000}
    );
});
```

The problem is, that in this solution animation goes very slow at first, then speeds up and after few minutes it is being done really fast. I am a javascript noob so I don't know a better solution.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `bg.jpg`?

Comment: it's 420x2300px and it's y-repeated. That is because it's a gradient image and scrolling this make the logo change its colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be problem with easing. You can try to use linear easing instead of the default jswing.

```
$('#logo').animate(
        {backgroundPosition: '0 -99999999px'},
        {duration: 5550000, easing: 'linear'}
    );
```